# Perl unicode handling with DBI

Tags: perl, encoding

I am using Spreadsheet::Read to get data from Excel (xls or xlsx) files and put them in a MySQL database using DBI.

If I print out the data to the console, it displays all special characters properly, but when I insert it into the database, some files end up with corrupted characters. For example, `"Möbelwerkstätte"` becomes `"MÃ¶belwerkstÃ¤tte"`.

I think that `Spreadsheet::Read` "knows" which character set is coming out of the file, as it prints properly to the console each time, regardless of the file encoding. How do I make sure that it is going into the database in UTF-8?

Comment: I believe DBI (and DBD::MySQL) defaults to Latin1. Send "USE NAMES utf8" as your first query. You could also enable it in my.cnf, please see MySQL docs.

Comment: You'll also need to make sure that the database schema has the [correct charset](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-applications.html) (the default is charset is Latin-1.)

Comment: Thank you @AndyThompson, that worked. If you write it up as a question I'll accept it. :-)

Comment: @friedo: The database was already in utf8. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both DBI and DBD::MySQL defaults to Latin1 (compiled with Latin1).
By sending "USE NAMES utf8" as your first query you will change it for that session.

From the manual:

SET NAMES indicates what character set the client will use to send SQL statements to the server. Thus, SET NAMES 'cp1251' tells the server, “future incoming messages from this client are in character set cp1251.” It also specifies the character set that the server should use for sending results back to the client. (For example, it indicates what character set to use for column values if you use a SELECT statement.)

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html for full documentation.

Answer (score 2):

The answer you have received (and accepted) already will probably work most of the time, but it's a little fragile and probably only works because Perl's internal character representation is a lot like UTF-8.

For a more robust solution, you should read the [Perl Unicode Tutorial](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlunitut.html) and follow the recommendations in there. They boil down to:

- Decode any data that you get from outside your program
- Encode any data that you send out of your program

In your case, you'll want to decode the data that you read from the spreadsheet and encode the data that you are sending to the database.